# How to get picturebox pixel color on mousemove

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to make drag and drop application . I drawn rectangle in run time and I want to detect if user try to move this rectangle or not

this is my code

```
        private bool Mouse_Down = false;

        Rectangle re = new Rectangle(100, 100, 60, 60);

        private void DrawRegion_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.RoyalBlue), re);

        }
        private void DrawRegion_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Mouse_Down == true) 
            { 
                re.Location = e.Location;

                if (re.Right > DrawRegion.Width)
                {
                    re.X = DrawRegion.Width - re.Width;
                }
                if (re.Top < 0)
                {
                    re.Y = 0;
                }
                if (re.Left < 0)
                {
                    re.X = 0;
                }
                if (re.Bottom > DrawRegion.Height)
                {
                    re.Y = DrawRegion.Height - re.Height;
                }
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void DrawRegion_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Mouse_Down = false;
        }

        private void DrawRegion_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Mouse_Down = true;
        }
```

For more details now this rectangle move either user click on this rectangle or in any empty space so I want to detect if clicked location color pixel is rectangle color pixel or not before moving rectangle how to do that ?

```
Note:DrawRegion is a picturebox
```

Sorry for bad English

Comment: Don't check colors. Keep track of the regions and compare the mouse location against those to determine if the mouse is over, inside, outside, etc. Checking for color will lead to issues down the road.

Comment: how to check the regions ? any way to do that ? i want to detect if this region is filled by this rectangle or not

Comment: Can you explain with code plz ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Rect.Contains()` to detect if your Rectaingle contain your current location

```
       private void DrawRegion_MouseClick(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (re.Contains(e.Location))
                Mouse_Down = true;
            else
                Mouse_Down = false;    
        }
```

check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557979(v=vs.110).aspx